# Index out of range when delete

Tags: java, string, compare

Can you help? Get error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1` when run this program. How to fix rhis? StringBuffer and StringTokenizer is necessary. Also, how can it be done simplier?

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class main {
  public static int i, n;
  public static boolean orly = false;
  public static StringBuffer input, tokenStr;
  public static StringTokenizer out;
  public static char aChar;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    input = new StringBuffer("some text");
    System.out.println("Начальная строка - " + input.toString());
    input = new StringBuffer(input.toString().replaceAll("[^a-z A-Z А-Я а-я]", ""));
    if (input.toString().trim().length() != 0) {
      out = new StringTokenizer(input.toString());
      System.out.println("Форматированая строка - " + input.toString());
      n = (out.countTokens());
      String[] charSet = { "a", "e", "o", "u", "y" };
      for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        tokenStr = new StringBuffer(out.nextToken());
        aChar = (tokenStr.charAt(0));
        String firstchar = tokenStr.toString().substring(0,1);
        if (tokenStr.length() > 1) {
          for (int i = 0; i <= charSet.length-1; i++) {
                if ((!firstchar.equals(charSet[i])) || (!firstchar.toUpperCase().equals(charSet[i]))) {
              input.delete(input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString()),input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString())+ tokenStr.length() + 1);
            }
         }
           } else {
                        input.deleteCharAt(input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
  //stuff
  if (tokenStr.length() > 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= charSet.length-1; i++) {
        //stuff
    }
  }
}
```

in the first for loop, you have a temporary variable i that exists only inside those curly braces. However, in your second for loop, you're creating another variable i. This i will overwrite the first one yet will still be incremented in both loops. You'd best rename the second one to j or something.

Additionally, in:

```
input.delete(input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString()),input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString())+ tokenStr.length() + 1);
```

What happens if tokenStr is not in input? Then indexOf will return -1 (predefined behaviour), which is causing this particular Exception.

- So.. I just need to delete all words in the String that not starts from "a", "e", "o", "u", "y", "i" and words with one char (like I, a). And create String with words that stay

Consider a different way. Rather than removing the unwanted words from the output StringBuffer, try adding wanted words to the output buffer as you find them. You can describe this logic to walking along your input string and writing down the words you want as you find them.

```
StringBuffer outString = new StringBuffer();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input.toString());
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
  String currentToken = (String)st.nextToken();
  if(currentToken.length() < 2){
    continue;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < charSet.length; i++){
    if(charSet[i] == currentToken.charAt(0)){
      outString.append(currentToken);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You may want to check your logic. What exactly are you trying to do with this code? Note that tokenStr won't necessarily be in input after the first round of deletions.

Comment: Well, you have to ensure that input.delete() takes in two valid numbers. I can't say all that much more without knowing what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: So.. I just need to delete all words in the String that not starts from "a", "e", "o", "u", "y", "i" and words with one char (like I, a). And create String with words that stay

Comment: It's easier to loop through StringTokenizer with while(st.hasMoreTokens()). Additionally, rather than putting things into the StringBuffer and then removing them, why not simply add things to it as you loop through the tokenizer?

Comment: Maybe. And this `if(charSet[i] == currentToken.charAt(0)){` is not correct